# url mod rewriting multiple parameters

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have these rules that i want to make it work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(view|show)/(ebook|lecture)/?$ page1.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/(view|show)/(ebook|lecture)/([^/]+)/?$ page2.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/-page-([0-9]+)?$ page3.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA]
```

My links are normally like this

```
www.domain.com/page1.php?a=view&b=ebook
www.domain.com/page2.php?a=view&b=ebook&c=title
www.domain.com/page3.php?a=title&b=6
```

and i want to turn them like the following look

```
www.domain.com/view/ebook           //page1
www.domain.com/view/ebook/title    //page2
www.domain.com/title/page-6       //page3
```

I've tried my rules but only the first one worked, But the page didn't load and the style was literally broken and not even a single image loaded or anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(view|show)/(ebook|lecture)/?$ page1.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?(view|show)/(ebook|lecture)/([^/]+)/?$ page2.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/page-([0-9]+)?$ page3.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA]
```

No leading slashes in left htaccess RewiteRule url (you can use `RewriteRule ^(view...`)
And you use only `page-` in your `www.domain.com/title/page-6       //page3` link (not `-page-`)